# How can I get a unique list of rows where a certain field is X?

Tags: mysql

With the table below, I want to get a id, form, value for each UNIQUE form from where value = 1.  I've tried `select id, form, value from tableName group by form` but the query returns ids 1 and 6, not ids 2 and 4 like I want.

EDIT 1&2: I am trying to use this in a subquery in a left outer join, but I am simply trying to get a list of all forms with value=1 if it exists, otherwise the value=0 result, in order to use in my join.  If I use `select id, form, value from tableName where value=1 group by form` I don't get the a2 or b1 forms.

```
id  form  value    
---|-----|------------
1  | a1  | 0
2  | a1  | 1
5  | a2  | 0 
3  | b1  | 0 
4  | c1  | 1 
6  | c1  | 0
```

The result I want is :

```
id  form  value    
---|-----|------------
2  | a1  | 1
5  | a2  | 0 
3  | b1  | 0 
4  | c1  | 1
```

Comment: How mysql is supposed to know what "you want" if you did not put it in the query? You are familiar with `WHERE` right?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want as your end result from the query

Comment: @zerkms see edit.  Thanks/sorry.

Comment: "I don't get the a2 or b1 forms." --- because they don't have `value=1`

Comment: So write 2 queries: one that returns groups that have `value=0` only (hint: use `HAVING` and `MAX(value) = 0`), and another that have `value=1`, and `UNION ALL` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT t.id, q.form, q.value
  FROM (
  SELECT form, MAX(value) value
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY form
) q JOIN table1 t 
    ON q.form = t.form
   AND q.value = t.value
```

Output:

```
| id | form | value |
|----|------|-------|
|  2 |   a1 |     1 |
|  5 |   a2 |     0 |
|  3 |   b1 |     0 |
|  4 |   c1 |     1 |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48f678/3)

Comment: Yes, thank you!!  I had not thought to just get a list of form and max(value) first, then join in the id back from the original table like that.  Great, and now I'll have a new approach in my toolkit moving forward.  Thanks again and have a great day!